# ordered containers in ios?

Tags: objective-c, ios, stl, containers

Are there any ordered containers such as C++ STL map, set in Objective-C, or am I supposed to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: There is no built-in one, but [you can borrow](https://github.com/MacBoyPro/treemapkit) some pre-written ones.

Comment: There is nothing preventing you from writing ObjectiveC++ code. So yes, you may use the template based containers when creating an iOS app and mix it with plain ObjectiveC wherever you need to.

Comment: @Till, just be careful when mixing C++ and Objective-C. ARC doesn't always like it.

Comment: nice ready http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/array.html

Comment: My advice: forget Objective-C.  If you can use C++.  However, if you use C++ and Objective-C together, I highly recommend you disable ARC for files which contains both C++ and Objective-C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSArray is an ordered container. If you're looking for an ordered map, no, it doesn't have that. A common solution is to use a normal NSDictionary and track ordering with either an array (if the ordering is arbitrary) or an NSSortDescriptor (if the ordering is based on something intrinsic to the objects).

Comment: I see. My question was actually if there is any containers like stl c++ containers in objective c. but I guess there is none. Thank you.

Comment: @inHisSteps: As I said, NSArray and NSDictionary are containers. They are not precisely cognate with C++ containers in every way, but they are broadly similar. If you're looking for something more, you'll need to explain.

Comment: I actually meant tree-structure containers like map or set. but it seems like there is not any built-in tree structure.

Comment: why is a map or a set a tree structure?

Comment: If your goal is to meld C++ and Objective-C, do so with care as others have said.  However, if your goal is to try to write Objective-C as if it were C++, expecting the same language services as C++ in ObjC (and the same patterns, then stop -- that path leads to failure.

Comment: @ vikingosegundo map is associative container and 'Associative containers are guaranteed to perform operations of insertion, deletion, and testing whether an element is in it, in logarithmic time - O(log n). As such, they are typically implemented using self-balancing binary search trees' from wiki

Comment: you shouldnt care about the implementation details of a collection. See the article I posted in a comment below your questions. Apple's containers seem to use different techniques for different amount of data.

Comment: "you shouldnt care about the implementation details of a collection" This is why I hate Objective-c.  If I don't know how the collection is implemented, then how on earth do I know if I want to use it? How do I optimize my code for it?  This just highlights the core problems with Obj-c and really all Apple SDKs: they are designed to dumb down programmers and train you not to ask questions.  C++ has 4 different kinds of maps, each with their own purpose, and the implementation details are not some grand mystery, it is a well known fact how each one is implemented because there is a spec.

Answer (score 3):

If you're asking about things like an array, Objective-C offers NSArray, NSSet, and NSDictionary. Each of those has a mutable variant. (NSMutableArray, NSMutableSet, and NSMutableDictionary, respectively.)

NSArray is an ordered set, NSSet is an unordered set. NSDictionary provides for key-value based storage.